Malicious file Modifications in WordPress Sites on Shared Hosting
I’ve been experiencing attacks on my WordPress sites hosted on a shared hosting plan from Namecheap. These attacks seem to originate through cPanel, where malicious file modifications are made via the File Manager. As a result, WordPress sites have become inaccessible.
One fix has been replacing the core WordPress files, but this is not a sustainable solution. I’ve already implemented security measures like WordFence and 2FA, yet the issue persists across all my sites.
Has anyone encountered this problem before? What are some effective long-term solutions to prevent such attacks, especially on shared hosting environments?

Consider rephrasing your question slightly to focus more on technical solutions for securing shared hosting environments and WordPress specifically.

1. Strengthen WordPress Security
Prevent attackers from editing themes or plugins directly by adding the following line to your wp-config.php file:
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);

2. Limit WordPress Admin Access:
Limit login attempts and restrict access to the WordPress dashboard (wp-admin) to specific IPs where feasible.
